# I want to get the image link inside a RSS feed description tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, substring, rss-reader

I want to get the image link inside a RSS feed description tag.

Using feedparser got the values in the discription tag.But i want to get the image link inside that tag.

```
<description><![CDATA[<div class="K2FeedImage"><img src="https://srilankamirror.com/media/k2/items/cache/25a3bb259efa21fc96901ad625f3a85d_S.jpg" alt="MP Piyasena sentenced to 4 years in prison" /></div><div class="K2FeedIntroText"><p>Former Tamil National Alliance (TNA) parliamentarian, P. Piyasena has been sentenced to 4 years in prison and fined Rs.</p>
</div><div class="K2FeedFullText">
<p>5.4 million for using state-owned vehicle for an year after losing his parliamentary seat.</p></div>]]></description>
```

Then i tried in his way using substring in python.

```
import re

text =  "<![CDATA[<img src='https://adaderanaenglish.s3.amazonaws.com/' width='60' align='left' hspace='5'/>Former Tamil National Alliance (TNA) MP P. Piyasena had been sentenced to 4 years in prison over a case of misusing a state vehicle after losing his MP post. MORE..]]>"

match = re.search("<img src=\"(.+?) \"", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

try:
    result = match.group(1)
except:
    result = "no match found"

print(result)
```

> C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/untitled/a.py
>
> > no match found
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image link without regular expression.Try the below code.It will first find the next_element and then get the soup again to get the image link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<description><![CDATA[<div class="K2FeedImage"><img src="https://srilankamirror.com/media/k2/items/cache/25a3bb259efa21fc96901ad625f3a85d_S.jpg" alt="MP Piyasena sentenced to 4 years in prison" /></div><div class="K2FeedIntroText"><p>Former Tamil National Alliance (TNA) parliamentarian, P. Piyasena has been sentenced to 4 years in prison and fined Rs.</p>
</div><div class="K2FeedFullText">
<p>5.4 million for using state-owned vehicle for an year after losing his parliamentary seat.</p></div>]]></description>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
item=soup.find('description')
data1=item.next_element
soup1=BeautifulSoup(data1,'html.parser')
print(soup1.find('img')['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://srilankamirror.com/media/k2/items/cache/25a3bb259efa21fc96901ad625f3a85d_S.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly alter your regular expression for it to work. What you want is to get the content right after `src=` and stop immediately (lazy search) when you meet the `'` character. So, your regex should be:

```
match = re.search("src='+(.*?)'",text)
```

You can visit [this](https://regex101.com/) to help you with your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use split. This is entirely dependent on you having already isolated the correct tag as you mention in your question. So, you are working with `text`.

```
text = '''
<description><![CDATA[<div class="K2FeedImage"><img src="https://srilankamirror.com/media/k2/items/cache/25a3bb259efa21fc96901ad625f3a85d_S.jpg" alt="MP Piyasena sentenced to 4 years in prison" /></div><div class="K2FeedIntroText"><p>Former Tamil National Alliance (TNA) parliamentarian, P. Piyasena has been sentenced to 4 years in prison and fined Rs.</p>
</div><div class="K2FeedFullText">
<p>5.4 million for using state-owned vehicle for an year after losing his parliamentary seat.</p></div>]]></description>
'''

link = text.split('src="')[1].split('"')[0] 
print(link)
```